# MySQL select data from 3 tables

Tags: mysql

I've 3 MySQL tables:

```
** cities **
------------------
id  name
------------------
1   New York
2   Los Angeles
3   San Francisco
...

** companies **
------------------
id  name
------------------
1   Company 1 Ltd.
2   Company 2 Ltd.
3   Company 3 Ltd.
...

** city_companies **
-------------------------
id  city_id  company_id
-------------------------
1   2        3
2   1        2
3   3        3
4   3        2
5   1        1
```

For example with this query:

```
SELECT a.*, c.*
FROM cities a
INNER JOIN city_companies b ON a.id = b.city_id
INNER JOIN companies c ON b.company_id = c.id
WHERE a.city_id = '1'
```

This query will return the list of companies that belongs to 'New York' (specified in 'city_companies' table). I need to get opposite result - list of companies that doesn't belong to 'New York'.

Comment: _select companies that are not added to city._ ????

Comment: _New York' should return 'Company 3 Ltd.' because it's not added in 'city_companies' table._ What about `Company 1 Ltd.` thats in New Your as well???

Comment: Your question is not clear. Read it back and try and edit it so you are sure we understand what you want

Comment: Off the top of my head I don't see any query that would take NY as input and give you Company 3 as output, but what you can do is do a LEFT JOIN and thus see where the missing values are - I ended up figuring something out, see my answer, let me know if it works for you.

Comment: can you share your schema

Comment: Yeah, I need to get list of companies that are not added to city. I need to get opposite result of 'city_companies' table.

Comment: try this 
select name from companies where not exists (
select 1 from cities inner join city_companies
on cities.id = city_companies.city_id 
inner join companies on companies.id = city_companies.company_id where cities.name = 'New York'
)

Comment: I just editied my question, maybe not it's more clear what I want to get.

Comment: I provided an answer that I think does what you're looking for. Can you test and tell me if it works ?

Comment: @VigoKrumins have you tried this
select name from companies where not exists ( select 1 from cities inner join city_companies on cities.id = city_companies.city_id inner join companies on companies.id = city_companies.company_id where cities.name = 'New York' )

Comment: @ChintanUdeshi it returns the list of companies that are added to 'New York'. I need the opposite result - companies that are not added to 'New York'.

Comment: can you share your schema and data on sqlfiddle

Comment: @ChintanUdeshi sqlfiddle is not working for me, when I open it, an alert appears saying that something wen wrong and I need to contact an administrator via email and schema is not building. In the developer console, there is javascript errors in page, saying that back-end server is at capacity.

Comment: try this select * from companies c where not exists (
select 1 from cities inner join city_companies on cities.id = city_companies.city_id inner join companies on companies.id = city_companies.company_id where cities.name = 'new york' and companies.id = c.id)

Comment: @ChintanUdeshi Finally! This method works, thanks mate! Great one!

Comment: @VigoKrumins yes great posted as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below query will give you expected output

```
select * from companies c where not exists ( 
select 1 from cities inner join city_companies on cities.id = city_companies.city_id inner join companies on companies.id = city_companies.company_id where cities.name 
= 'new york' and companies.id = c.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS cities;

CREATE TABLE cities 
(id  INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

INSERT INTO cities VALUES
(1,'New York'),
(2,'Los Angeles'),
(3,'San Francisco');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS companies;

CREATE TABLE companies 
(id  INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

INSERT INTO companies VALUES
(1,'Company 1 Ltd.'),
(2,'Company 2 Ltd.'),
(3,'Company 3 Ltd.');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS city_companies;

CREATE TABLE city_companies
(city_id INT NOT NULL
,company_id INT NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(city_id,company_id)
);

INSERT INTO city_companies VALUES
(2,3),
(1,2),
(3,3),
(3,2),
(1,1);


SELECT DISTINCT x.*
  FROM companies x 
  JOIN city_companies xy1 
    ON xy1.company_id = x.id 
  JOIN cities y 
    ON y.id = xy1.city_id 
  LEFT 
  JOIN city_companies xy2 
    ON xy2.company_id = xy1.company_id 
   AND xy2.city_id <> xy1.city_id 
  LEFT 
  JOIN cities y2 
    ON y2.id = xy2.city_id 
   AND y2.name = 'new york' 
 WHERE y.name <> 'new york' 
   AND y2.id IS NULL;
id  name
 3  Company 3 Ltd.
```

http://rextester.com/CRULQ65167

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select *
from cities
left join city_companies on cities.id =  city_companies.city_id
left join companies on companies.id = city_companies.company_id
where 
cities.name != 'New York';
```

Comment: Except for the special case of `IS NULL`, `LEFT JOIN x... WHERE x` is the same as `INNER JOIN x...`

Comment: if you want the reverse of your table "city_companies", then you just need to adjust the previous query: where cities.name is NOT NULL and companies.name is NULL;

Comment: @Strawberry yes, except one is LEFT JOIN the other is INNER JOIN. Or am I missing something ?

Comment: Yes. You're missing something.

Comment: I see what you mean. Except that in our case, we want to look for the "special case" is null. So we need a left join and not an inner one.

Comment: In other words. Change `where` to `and`. And change `and` to `where`.

Comment: If I do that, the query would no longer work. But maybe I'm missing something again. In its actual form it responds to the question.

Comment: Using this, it returns empty result. And same when changing 'where' to 'and', and changing 'and' to 'where'. No luck.

Comment: @VigoKrumins I've updated the query. It should give you the companies that are not associated with NY.

Comment: @Bogdan Thanks for helping, but not return the result that I need. I've tried to use SELECT inside of INNER JOIN but still not returning what I need.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT companies.name from companies
WHERE companies.name NOT IN
(SELECT companies.name FROM companies 
INNER JOIN city_companies ON companies.id = city_companies.company_id
INNER JOIN cities ON city_companies.city_id = cities.id
WHERE cities.name = 'New York');
```